# Problems with angular validation in directive

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I am fighting with the validation in an angular directive without success.

The form.name.$error object seems to be undefined, when I submit the name property to the directive template. If i use a fixed name-attribute inside the template, the $error object is fine, but of course identical for all elements.

The html is:

```
 <form name="form" novalidate>

<p>
  <testvalidation2 name="field1" form="form"  field="testfield4" required="true"> 
  </testvalidation2>
</p>
</form>
```

The directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('testvalidation2', function(){
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  ngModel: '=',
  newfield: '=field',
  required: '=required',
  form: '='
},
templateUrl: 'template2.html',
link: function(scope, element, attr){
 scope.pattern = /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/;
 scope.name = attr.name;
}
```

} // return
});`

and finally the template:

```
<div>
<input  name="{{name}}" type="text" ng-model="newfield" ng-required="required" ng-pattern="pattern"> {{FIELD}}</input>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.required">Required</span>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.pattern"> Invalid </span>
<p>Output {{form.name.$error | json}}</p>
</div>
```

I have created a plunker for my [Angular Validation Problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/FK4zhEOTEtAmgZ1Nx82I)
and would be happy, if someone would help me to win the fight.

Michael

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fix for this but I can tell you what the problem is.

- Firstly in your html `form="form"` should have name of the form `form="form2"`.
- Secondly Since you are creating a new scope in the directive, the scope created is a isolated scope which does not inherit from parent, which means that the the template `input` control that you add would not get added to the parent scope `form2`.

The only way out currently i can think of is to not use isolated scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.Thanks for pointing to the form/form2 mismatch. This didn't fix the problem. I think that it is related to the scope, but the other attributes like required, ngModel are transfered to the directive scope. It seems that the name-attribute is not available to the directive $error-object.